# Textarea with javascript can't send in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, validation, textarea

I 'm having a submit form for writing a text. One part of it is that people can add a list to their text if it's needed. Because the list isn't necessarily included in every upload (it's an upload of texts with forms by the way, not files) and I thought it would be nice that you can click a button to show up a textarea if you need it. The problem is, I 'm using a javascript which looks like this:

```
<script>
function Words()
{
    document.getElementById('wordinput').innerHTML= '<textarea name="words" cols="50" rows="4"></textarea>';
}
</script>
```

although it works fine in the HTML, it seems like the PHP at the next page doesn't interpret this piece of code, although it's very simple HTML. I guess it only interprets everything which is loaded already and not the stuff which is added later with Javascript. But are there ways outside of AJAX to still do it or is AJAX simply necessary? And if so, can I just get this function in AJAX or do I have to re-write my whole code and change the upload form with a new AJAX text and change all the other HTML which doesn't use Javascript and add ids to submit them?

Here is relevant code:

```
echo "<tr><td><input type='button' onclick='Words()' value='Add words'></button>";
echo "<div id='wordinput'></div>";
echo "<tr><td>Course: <textarea name='text' cols='50' rows='10'></textarea></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'></td></tr>";
```

The form starts like this:

```
echo "<form action='addcoursetodatabase.php' method='post'>";
```

The relevant PHP:

```
$words=$_POST["words"];

if($_POST['words'])
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO courses (username, title, language, course, difficulty,   vocabulary) VALUES     ('".$_SESSION['user']."','$title','$language','$text','$difficult','$words')");
}
else
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO courses (username, title, language, course, difficulty) VALUES      ('".$_SESSION['user']."','$title','$language','$text','$difficult')");
}
```

Comment: "it seems like the PHP at the next page doesn't interpret this piece of code" — PHP will never see that code. It will only see what the browser submits, and the browser doesn't care if a textarea element was generated via HTML or JavaScript.

Comment: In that case I really don't understand what is wrong, because I used $_POST['words'] in the PHP, which should be inputted in mySQL. When this code was just generated via HTML it worked fine, but when I added the Javascript it stopped working. :S

Comment: You haven't described yourself as doing anything wrong. Whatever the problem is, it isn't revealed by any information you've put in the question.

Comment: Are you actually adding it inside of the form element?

Comment: The id is added inside the form element. But the script is inside the head tags, I 'm not sure IF it's the problem, but it might be. The only problem is that if I try to put it somewhere else in the code where it might work, I get errors.

Comment: I just tested it with input type='text' and in that case it works neither. The problems started when inserting it as Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly then you need to make sure the textarea is added inside the Form tags of the form on the page. Then yo should be able to see the data inside "words" which is the name of your  textarea.

Comment: I 'm used to inputting Javascript between the <head> tags because I actually haven't used Javascript all that much. Just a few times. I 'm trying to input it in the form now, but I get syntax errors, so I need to try how to input it inside the PHP code.

Comment: What i mean is that your element with the id of wordinput is inside form tags with the method as POST so your php will pick it up

Comment: Yes it is, but does it make a difference if you use a <div> element or a <p> element? Because the output is the same if you change it to a textarea, but I don't know if that matters for PHP. The script itself wasn't within the form though, but I 'm not sure if it's supposed to be because it gives me syntax errors every time and within the <head> elements the function works fine. Except for the function not submitting to the PHP code.

Comment: no the script doesnt need to be on the page but i was sayihg you needed to make sure the textarea was being added into the form. if it was not inside form tags it would not work. also if you are running jQuery then you can use append

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it. I still don't know how to do it with Javascript, for some strange reason it never works, but I just inputted the textarea inside the HTML code with a  and used jQuery to hide it at the load of the document and show it when clicking a button. This works fine. I recommend other people with the same problem to just use jQuery, because Javascript without jQuery doesn't seem to be able to do it.

Comment: I had the same problem. From what I recall, using the innerHTML method you described adds the field to the page but doesn't embed it into the form, so posting wouldn't send the text within.  I can't remember exactly how I fixed it, but I recall I had use CreateELement and append it to the form.  Eventually, I switched to jQuery and was able to create the element with no problem.  The solution you presented is much simpler, though and one I was about to propose.

Comment: if you were already using jQuery then you could of appended it to the div and it would of worked

Comment: Lee: Well, I was not using jQuery for this page. I was just using jQuery for another part of the site, but for all the other parts I don't use jQuery. But the solution works anyway.